# %H:%M:%S.%f format is not consistant in my pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time

I have the following code:
`y_df['TimeFormat'] =  pd.to_datetime(x_df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f'))`
But the problem is the format of x_df['Time'] is not always %H:%M:%S.%f. Meaning that its format is sometimes %H:%M:%S. I can easily delete the format and let python does its job. However, that would significantly increase the computational time. I was wondering if there is a way to convert all the instances of x_df['Time'] into the above format in an automatic way.

Comment: Scroll down to "dateutil" in this article, it automatically parses dates, which might help:  https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) it can create datetime objects from different strings automatically:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse 

parse('12:03:24')                                                                                                                                                                                 
# datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 8, 12, 3, 24)

parse('12:03:24.0003')                                                                                                                                                                            
# datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 8, 12, 3, 24, 300)
```

You can convert to a pandas timestamp from the datetime timestamp:

```
pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 8, 12, 3, 24, 300))                                                                                                                                      
# Timestamp('2019-12-08 12:03:24.000300')
```

or

```
pd.Timestamp(parse('12:03:24'))
# Timestamp('2019-12-08 12:03:24')

pd.Timestamp(parse('12:03:24.3333'))
#  Timestamp('2019-12-08 12:03:24.333300')
```